# What is the ratio $c:a$ given that $c^2=a^2+ac$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the ratio $c:a$ given that $c^2=a^2+ac$? I'm not sure why I'm blocking on this but I can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Divide through by $a^2$ then rearrange...

Hint 2: treat $c\over a$ as a quantity to be solved for in its own right.

Hint 3: substituting $x=\frac ca$ and rearranging, we get

$$x^2-x-1=0$$

Comment: Thanks! Okay so that gives me c/a=(c^2/a^2) - 1, but I'm still lost as to how I should proceed from there haha.

Comment: Hint 3 should make it clear. :-)

Comment: Thankyou! I hadn't even thought of that. So then that should give me ((1+sqrt(5))/2) and ((1-sqrt(5))/2) ... Sorry, just signed up so I'll figure out how to use the stack edit asap.